# typescript: `{ key(): type }` vs `{ key: () => type }`

Tags: typescript

A co-worker just wrote this in a PR and I was surprised that it worked since I'd never seen the syntax.

Is there any difference between these?

```
type x = {
    foo(): void;
    bar: () => void;
}

const x: x = {
    foo: () => { },
    bar: () => { }
}
```

[playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20x%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo()%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20x%3A%20x%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: It's pretty much the same as far as I can tell. One difference is that `this` is bound to the including object within fat-arrow (`=>`) functions (see [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20x%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo()%3A%20void%3B%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20x%3A%20x%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20function()%20%7B%20alert(this.foo)%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20alert(this.foo)%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ax.foo()%3B%0Ax.bar()%3B%0A))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first (`foo(): void;`) one is a method definition, the second (`bar: () => void;`) is a field definition that happens to be of a function type (`() => void;`)

The obvious difference is the icon used in intelisene for code completion.

Functionally in most cases there is no difference. For classes methods are assigned to the prototype while fields are usually assigned to the instance, but this is just an object type so where the function is assigned is really up to the object doing the implementation not to the type itself.

The one big difference as far as types go is the behavior under `strictFunctionTypes` ([pr](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654)). The gist of it is that methods behave bivariantly while field behave contravariantly so only one is an error in the code below:

```
type x = {
    foo(x: number | string): void;
    bar: (x: number | string) => void;
}

const x: x = {
    foo: (x: number) => { },// this is fine, methods are bivariant 
    bar: (x: number) => { } // err here, fields are contravariant  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as only the types are considered, there's no difference:

```
type x = {
    foo(): void;
    bar: () => void;
}


type Foo = x['foo'];
type Bar = x['bar'];
// both are () => void
```

In general, the type of `this` inside a method or arrow function body is not part of the method or arrow function type.

Comment: I disagree about the lack of difference in type for method vs field for functions. Sure for `()=> void` there is no difference since there are no arguments but they do behave differently

Comment: Yeah it's one of those invisible differences which you constantly need to be aware of - there's no indication in the error message why `foo` is OK and `bar` is not in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those fun little typing surprises.